# six months and no major change in losing fat

Tags: weight-loss, burn-fat

I been on a [plan](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/kris-gethin-12-week-daily-trainer.html) for 6 months, i eat according to the [nutrition](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/gethin-nutrition-plan.html) and also the [supplement](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/kris-gethin-12-week-daily-trainer-supplement-guide.html). Although it is 12 weeks program but as for me its been 6 months and i am hardly seeing any results. Now i have come to a point where my motivation is going below due to results. The belly fat is still there. However i do have increase in strength according to my gym, as they run assessment like how much pushup in 1 minute or crunches and my score has improved but not as much as i wanted (i had fat of 24% in Nov.14 and 22% in Dec.14). According to the plan, if your not sore from previous day workout, it means it wasn't a good working (meaning you didn't push yourself). However i use to have "sore days" but not anymore. Just light or not at all. So all of my motivation is coming down as i don't see any big changes. Like for 6 months or more, i been taking

1. L-Carnitine (1000 mg)
2. Green Tea
3. BCAA
4. Glutamine
5. and creatine

having said that, it also worries me for the effect it has on body. What should i do to torch up my body fat and get shredded.

Comment: Based on your information, i think your body already adapt to your workouts and you need to increase your intensity + consistency and motivation. Just focus on your goals.

Comment: @Kerppag How do i increase intensity?

Comment: this is a good [article](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/8-easy-ways-to-increase-training-intensity.html) on how to increase your workout intensity .

Comment: How much weight have you lost within that timeframe? How much body fat? And more importantly, how dedicated were you to the program?

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD 3.5 kg in 6 months, 3 % body fat and I been doing it daily. Sometimes I do miss it e.g some family emergency but I make up for it.

Comment: If you're stalling on weight loss but still dropping bodyfat %, all that means is you're just putting on muscle weight while losing fat weight. A 2% drop in bodyfat over just 30 days is great progress, so keep it up!

Comment: So a nice quote from Dan John is:"Everything (exercise program in this case) works for about 6 weeks". 6 months without any significant progress is a big red flag in my opinion. Not saying your gym doesn't know their stuff but I do get the feeling you should be trying something else

Comment: @Gordijn_forsale like what? I can hire a PT but they are just helping with weights, like a spotter and nothing else. They push u, that's all but too expensive for that kind of helping hand.

Comment: @Nofel Really depends on your goals and the amount of time and energy your willing to invest, but I would suggest trying a powerlifting program (mainly because of the compound exercises and neccesary technique) such as stronglifts.

Answer (score 4):

I'll be honest, 6 months is a long time to see no change at all.  Are you tracking changes other than what the scale tells you?  For example, just using a tape measure will help you figure out if your gut is really getting smaller or not.  Once a week I take several measurements to determine if I like the way things are progressing:

- Neck
- Shoulders
- Chest
- Arm (triceps and biceps)
- Forearm
- Abdomen
- Hips
- Thigh
- Calf

I lose weight very slowly, on the order of about 10-20 lbs a year (5-10kg) so I can identify with how demotivating it can be to just look at a scale.  In that same time, I can lose several inches and go down in size but not so much weight.  The loss of inches helps keep me motivated.

**Figuring Out the Diet**

As long as you eat good food, and avoid restaurants when possible, there are a number of areas where your fat loss journey might get into trouble:

- *You're eating too much.*  Periodically, you have to reduce the amount of food you eat to compensate for your smaller size and keep losing weight.  When you don't see any change for a couple weeks (inches or weight), it's time to reduce your food by 200-300 Calories a day.
- *You're not eating the right things.*  You need a certain amount of protein, fat, and carbs to support your activity.  Keep your protein somewhat high (1.8g protein/kg body weight), and play with the ratio of fat to carbs for the remainder of the calories.  I found that I work better with lower fat and more carbs.  Some find that they do better the opposite.
- *You aren't sleeping enough.*  Your body needs sleep to build muscle and burn fat.  If you can give yourself a consistent 8 hour block a night for sleeping, you'll be in the best shape for both.  When you can sleep for about that long and wake up without an alarm you will be refreshed, be able to think more clearly, and lower blood pressure and improve a myriad of other health markers.  Getting proper sleep should be a priority to anyone trying to lose weight and/or build muscle.

There's always the chance that you have something more going on with your body like an inflamed gall bladder, insufficient iodine in the diet to support proper thyroid function, etc.  However, the three bullets address the top contenders for why you aren't losing weight and/or inches.

**Figuring out Exercise**

Muscle soreness really is a poor indicator of how hard you are working.  All it means is that you did something your body isn't used to.  I find that after a layoff my body can get very sore from even a light workout.  I'm just starting back in the gym after a surgery, and even though the weights I'm using are very light for me I'm incredibly sore.  Once I'm back in the swing of things, I can be using twice the weight I am now with the same number of reps and not feel sore at all.

That said, there's some ways to ensure you are hitting your goals:

- *Progressive Overload:* You should be getting stronger, even while losing weight.  Over time you should be increasing weight, reps, speed, etc.  If bodybuilding is your primary goal, I'd recommend a progression where you start with a challenging 3x8 and keep adding reps until you get to 3x12 with that weight.  Then increase by 5-10 lbs and start over at 3x8.  When you run out of being able to increase that way, switch to the 3-5 rep range and do more sets.
- *Cardiovascular Work:* I find that I lose weight best when I have a good cardiovascular base.  That can mean limiting the rest between sets or exercises.  It can also mean metabolic conditioning using barbell complexes, or simply riding a bike or walking for a couple miles a day.  It doesn't have to be high intensity for it to work.  In fact low intensity cardio like walking briskly can help with active recovery while also helping to burn some fat.
- *Recovery:* You can get to a point where you have too much stress and your body is just not able to keep up.  Food and sleep are your primary tools to help with recovery.  Sometimes you just need a rest from training.  The rest can be complete rest from weight training for a week, or it can be working with lighter weights and doing a relative rest.  You can schedule these as often as once a month, or infrequently as you feel like you really need it.  Just pay attention to the signals your body is giving you.  If you are getting the proper nutrition and sleeping 8 hours a day but still feeling lethargic and are unable to think clearly, you need to rest from training for a little bit and let your body catch up.

**Summary**

Hopefully these tips will help you figure out what's going wrong, and fix it.  Keep your motivation up, and give yourself more than just one way of tracking progress.  You'll find that the progress is happening, but for whatever reason it's not quite the way you were thinking.  The body is a very complex system, and every step you take to get a bit stronger and closer to the 10-15% body fat goal (for men, the equivalent for women would be a bit higher), the healthier it will be.

Comment: If i do Progressive overweight, i heard someone say, do more weight but rest for 2-3 minute. Is that correct as i need to rebuild energy for my remaining sets with that heavy weight.

Comment: Progressive **overload** just means you are pushing yourself more and more over time.  As I mentioned in the bullet there are _several_ ways of doing that.  If you get more reps with the same weight, you've increased.  If you cut your rest times and did the same work, you've increased.  If you add more weight, you've increased.  Rest times are just one thing you can manipulate for your training.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but my gf was also struggling with her weight after working abroad for 2 years, I recommended she employ some weight training more specifically compound movements (squat variations and dead-lifts), along with her normal cardio. It worked wonders for her, but what's good for the gander isn't always good for the goose but I do recommended you try adding atleast 1 compound weightlifting exercise. It really does make you feel amazing :).

Another thing she found is that starving herself didn't aid weight loss, it appeared to limit it. I suspect the body goes into "drought mode" and reserves fat when not enough calories are being taken in. This is purely speculation atm I haven't researched the matter.

Comment: hormones are really important in weight loss which is why the starving probably didn't work, starving yourself causes your body to go into storage mode

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry if you don't feel sore, most people don't feel sore after every session, especially not if they are accustomed to exercising. Both soreness and muscle rebuilding is connected to microtears in your muscles though. What you might want to try is to increase the focus on the eccentric phase (lengthening) when working out, so if you're bench pressing, push the bar up explosively and let it take two seconds from the top to your chest, soreness is caused by the eccentric phase of a lift.

Also make sure you rest enough and you're challenging yourself in every workout, if you can have a neutral face, it's too light.

Regarding fat loss, what method are you using? If you're counting calories, you might be exaggerating both your basal metabolism and the number of calories used when workout out. Most calculators used exaggerates a lot since A. Some basal metabolism formulas are based on people living in the 1910's, and they had a lot more lean mass than people do today.

B. Calories per hour calculators include both the "extra" calories used in the activity and the calories from your basal metabolism, so if a calculator says you used 700 kcal during 60 minutes, you'll have to subtract 100 kcal since those are already included in your basal metabolism.

All in all, decrease your calorie intake and you WILL see fat loss eventually.